# How to update ruby in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I downloaded ruby trhrough the rails installer but i now want ruby 2.0.0 and already downloaded it. how do i update my ruby because whe i do

`ruby -v`

it still comes up as ruby version 1.9.3.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The easiest way for you might be to use RubyInstaller, which its version 2.0.0-p0 is now available for download as installers. Follow the link http://rubyinstaller.org/ for more information.

Comment: yea that is what i did, do i just delete 1.9.3 in the c directory and create a new path for 2.0.0?

Comment: On the announcement they stated _"DO NOT install Ruby 2.0 on top of existing Ruby 1.9.3, or try to use compiled 
extensions with it."_ (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/mg5ailNICvM/discussion). So yes, just go ahead and delete the previous version and install the new one. Good luck!

Comment: This takes inordinately long - est. 15 mins - and doesn't work for me. When I type `ruby -v` it stil shows up as 2.2.4 instead of 2.5.

Answer (score 42):

I recommend using Chocolatey to manage your ruby installation.

It's a unix style package manager for windows.

It's quite easy to install, you can find instructions on [their website](https://chocolatey.org/install).

In cmd.exe (run as administrator):

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin
```

Then you can install ruby:

```
choco install ruby
```

And upgrade it later:

```
choco upgrade ruby
```

Comment: I think this is a better option

Answer (score -4):

Either You can go with new Installer or use "gem"(ruby package manager)  to update.

Comment: @earl3s was right. RubyGems is only providing gems not Ruby!