# i'm try to install ruby on rail , after installing cocoapods but it has same error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rubygems

Installing cocoapods gives the following error:

```
:~$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Fetching: nap-1.1.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: fuzzy_match-2.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: cocoapods-core-1.2.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
cocoapods-core requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

Comment: have look here... https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4711

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the Ruby version, you are using an old version of Ruby.

Check out this post to see how to update the Ruby version if you are using MAC

[How to update Ruby Version 2.0.0 to the latest version in Mac OSX Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-to-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-osx-yosemite#)

or this for windows

[How to update ruby in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722703/how-to-update-ruby-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest workaround is actually installing version 4.2.6 of activesupport manually:

`$ sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
$ sudo gem install cocoapod`